# How does one make pixel art for a game?

Tags: background, coronasdk, pixel

I am programming an app using Corona SDK and I was wondering how you make pixel art for the app. I can't afford anything like Photoshop.

The thing that really confuses me is how people make a big background and then make it display pixels, like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=firefox-a&hs=yUl&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&q=big%20pixels&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0CE4QBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.56343320,d.dmg,pv.xjs.s.en_US.xTHDqTyMTwg.O&biw=1920&bih=956&dpr=1&ech=1&psi=j9WCUuPUHcb_4AOutoCwAg.1384306064193.7&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&ei=n9WCUrO2DZen4AOx7oHoBA&gws_rd=cr#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=8uikmu_68A1IhM%3a;JWQ2l8J5GZDJGM;http%253A%252F%252Fthumbs.dreamstime.com%252Fz%252Fglass-wine-big-pixels-27829705.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.dreamstime.com%252Froyalty-free-stock-photo-glass-wine-big-pixels-image27829705;1300;1390)

If you zoom in far enough to use pixels, it just goes back to looking like a line when I zoom back out.

I want to make a background made of big pixels that is 1024x768. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw large colored squares that look like pixels?

Comment: MSPaint is pretty cutting-edge in this domain.

Comment: @Aaron How would I use Paint to do this?

Comment: Sarcasm aside; Draw it as individual pixels while zoomed in, then resize the canvas to something larger. Make sure you choose the correct interpolation (nearest-neighbour?) so that you get sharp lines and not blurs.

Comment: This is going to sound stupid, but what about when it is zoomed in taking a screen shot and save that as a file?  Does that work?  Or did I completely misunderstand the question?

Comment: I am not sure also if I understood clearly your request (because I don't think it is related directly to Corona SDK), but one advice : be careful of anti-aliasing when you zoom / strech an image.

Comment: Don't use MSPaint, use Paint.Net. Supports transparant backgrounds out of the box etc.

Answer (score 1):

GIMP is an open source, free image editing software. It is quite powerful.

http://www.gimp.org/

I don't believe this question belongs on this site, for future reference though.

Answer (score 0):

After drawing what you want while zoomed in in Paint, try:

```
Ctrl-A
Resize and Skew (Ctrl-W in Windows 7)
500% width and height
Okay Button
If you need larger pixels, repeat.
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to create pixel art . But i really suggest you go with Piskel . I have used it a lot and I think it is pretty good . You can also try PixilArt.

Piskel : piskelapp.com

PixilArt : pixilart.com/draw

I hope this helps